# How to Set Column Widths in HTML5 Table with colSpan > 1 in First Row

Tags: html, css

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col indicates that the `width` attribute of the <col> element (used in a <colgroup>) has been made obsolete in HTML5.

1. Why? Where are developers expected to find the actual reasoning behind decisions like this?
2. What is the recommended way to set column widths now? (presumably the spec didn't intend to remove the ability to set column widths)

Specifically, how do the spec authors expect to control the width of each column in a table where the first row is the year (spanning 52 columns), the second row is the month (12 groups each spanning either 4 or 5 columns), and the third row is the week (1 column each). (the point here is you can't use the first row to set the column widths since it spans multiple columns).

Comment: can you give an exemple of what you want to achieve ? Also, I believe the attribute is depracted so doing <colgroup width="200">, but you can still set it via CSS using class

Comment: @Crocsx I want to explicitly set the width of each column in a table, which could be done by explicitly specifying the width of each cell in the first row, unless cells in the first row span more than one column. Refer to the link in my original question indicating that the width tag is obsolete (not just depreciated), which is confirmed in the standard https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-col-element since it doesn't mention the width attribute at all.

Comment: @Crocsx What you described seems to still work, but my expectation is that if something like this is made obsolete, the people who decided to make it obsolete had some sort of replacement in mind, so I want to try and find out what they had in mind.

Comment: so yes, the width tag is obsolete, you can still indeed use css as I said. 

as for who decided what is HTML5 standard or not, WHATWG is in charge of continuously shaping HTML and web technologies